# Requested *contact information of two references* in application for a PhD

Tags: phd, recommendation-letter, email

I just find an interesting call for a PhD position. In order to apply one has to submit, among all the standard thing as cv and transcript of records, also **contact information of two references**. I don't know what does this mean. Does it mean that I have to attach in the email also the contacts of two of my professors?

Regards

Comment: One obvious but important note, just to be sure that there is no misunderstanding: You need to ask the people if they are willing to act as a reference before handing out their contacts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to supply the contact information.

So:
Address (postal)
Email address
Telephone number(s) landline definitely, mobile not always

This is so that the admissions / adjudicating committee can get a reference according to their policy. That could be a 5 minute chat or asking the referee for a personal letter, or sending the referee a particular form to be completed.

Whatever they want, you need to supply the contact information. Be sure that if you don't then it will negatively affect your application, even to the point that it gets binned immediately. They have too many to waste time coming back to you "oh, you forgot the contact info for 2 referees"...

Comment: email address will completely suffice. no one is going to send them a letter, and calling them without emailing them beforehand would also be rather uncommon.

Comment: @user151413 I have been « cold » called by hr about a particular candidate, and the hr person was actually an ex-student of mine so I answered based on experience. I notice that you mention just the same things in your answer...

Comment: If it someone you have a relationship with (like former student etc.), cold calling is ok.  Then it's more like luke-warm.  But then you most likely also know how to reach the person. If I don't know someone reasonably well, I would email beforehand and ask for an assessment or a brief call.

Comment: @user151413 I don’t keep info on ex-students so I have no means of reaching out to them. It is still normal to cold call people - do you email a plumber before phoning them?

Comment: I'm sorry, but we are not talking about plumbers. Comparing this is plain silly. We are talking about giving a - confidential, informed, well thought through - assessment about a student.  In that case, I appreciate if I have a moment to think about what to say, since it is important for the student, but also for the caller and me.

Comment: @user151413 take as much time as you like, but when I am asked to take a call, I have the manners not to refuse it and handle it appropriately - even searching out the relevant information such as my original copy of the reference letter, the grades I awarded and any other pertinent info I have recorded. So I am informed about that student and can answer queries that are within my sphere. If those queries are about a different subject then I cannot. And you can be as sorry as you want.

Comment: That's why I want to be notified ahead: So I can pull up this information. And, if it is a *proper* student of mine, like someone having done a project with me, or a master's thesis, or the like: To carefully think about my assessment in the context of the application.

Comment: I would have a further question: In the case where they ask for a reference letter, should the referee have already wtitten the letter, or do they let him/er time to write it?

Comment: @AbelMilor yes. As in sometimes a pre-written reference is suitable and other times one is written “new” for that application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should provide ways in which two people - either professors or senior postdocs - who can say something substantial about you can be reached.  Most likely, an email address will suffice.  You can also provide a phone number.  Listing their affiliation (i.e. University of X) is also a good idea. Mailing address is certainly overkill (but won't hurt either).

In general, I would recommend to rather list someone less "professorial" who can say something more substantial about you, rather than the other way - certainly for one of the two references, this would be fine.  It is much better to have someone who has worked with you on a project, thesis, or the like, rather than someone who just knows you from one course - it is much harder to get substantial feedback in such cases. (After all, for a PhD people are not so much interested how you do in coursework, but how you do in research projects.)